# Solr 7.7 JSON transformer is not working on escaped array of structs

Tags: solr

I can't get a proper json response from Solr string field

So I got a table with some sort of key and array of structs that I need to get. That array is properly escaped and stored as string (StrField in Solr schema).

The problem is -

```
select?fl=id,num,fieldName:[json]&rows=1&wt=json
```

is not working, I'm still getting result as a string.

Result example below:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":12,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "fl":"id,num,fieldName:[json]",
      "rows":"1",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1566936035651"}},
  "response":{"numFound":367350,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {

      "id":"a0740a195708db8674f64858dcbdb36e325df1176cb3d608922c000b11a4f2d5",
      "num":"536759483354",
      "fieldName":"[{\"field1\":3974488417,\"field2\":\"2720286642123\",\"field3\":\"ХХХХ\"}]"}]
  }}
```

Though I'm querying it in Solr interface, but I guess it shouldn't matter. 
My Solr is 7.7, so it should work, but it doesn't.

What I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it (get a proper json out of request)?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `fieldName:[json]`?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Too bad its just a question typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformers [json] & [xml] won't work in a sharded setup. You have to have only one shard on your collection to make use of those transformers.

The issue has been open in Solr bug tracker since 2016:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9376?jql=project%20%3D%20SOLR%20AND%20text%20~%20%22json%20transformer%22

Please consider upvoting it to get it resolved quicker.

Before it is resolved, we have to parse the json string on the client.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I looked for! Indeed, we had some cases when json transformation worked as intended, and some cases where it didm't work, its just I never thought it was about shards.